# Reading/accessing mails from already opened outlook account in Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, jakarta-mail

Is there a way to check emails in an already open Outlook application, with or without using API mail? For example; My application sends out an email for any activity performed and the same email appears in already opened Outlook. I need to check if I have got the email in my inbox/folder from specific "email ID".

Comment: Could you use the JavaMail api to query your inbox on your SMTP server? (rather than trying to interact with the Outlook client directly?)

Comment: Yes, but you'll need to use IMAP, not SMTP, to read the messages from the server.  It's not clear why you want the message to be already "opened" in Outlook.  Do you want your program to only see the message if it's also being viewed by the user in Outlook?

Answer (score 0):

You're much better off using some mail service like [nDumbster](https://github.com/EdenRidgway/nDumbster) or [Papercut](https://papercut.codeplex.com/) to act as an SMTP sink that "catches" the mail.

Working with Outlook, GMail, or any other real mail service makes your tests too complex, slow, and brittle. It took me a long time to understand that...